# Access methods in user control not possible although public

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, methods, user-controls

It seems to be an easy question and I could find some postings related to it here which - unfortunately - did not help me in the end.

What I am trying to do is to access methods in a user control.

What I did: Set up the user control "TabContent" like this:

```
namespace TabContent
{
    public partial class TabContent : UserControl
    {
        public TabContent()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public void SetName(string tabname)
        {
            show_name.Text = tabname; //show_name is a label
        }

    }
}
```

Now I am trying to access it from my main application:

```
using TabContent;

namespace Tab_Test
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void buttonItem1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            UserControl lab = new TabContent.TabContent();            
            lab.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
            lab.SetText("hallo");
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that the method SetText() is not known although it is defined as public and I also added "using TabContent". I left out some code where a new tab is created and the user control displayed in this tab. This works fine so the user control exists and works, just that I do not seem to have access to the methods.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Because you're declaring lab as UserControl and it has not a SetText/SetName method. Change that line to var lab = new TabContent.TabContent();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You variable is of type `UserControl`, which does not have a `SetName` method. Use the `var` feature or make your variable an explicit type `TabContent.TabContent`.

```
private void buttonItem1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var lab = new TabContent.TabContent();            
            lab.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
            lab.SetName("hallo");
        }
```

OR

```
private void buttonItem1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            TabContent.TabContent lab = new TabContent.TabContent();            
            lab.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
            lab.SetName("hallo");
        }
```

Comment: thanks, that indeed solved the problem and it is working as expected now!

Answer (score 1):

Method name is `SetName` you are trying to call `SetText`. And change `UserControl lab =` to `var lab =` or `TabContent.TabContent lab =`

Comment: I don't think the downvote is warranted either. I added the text suggested in this answer, and I can demonstrate compiler errors when my project looks like the original, which are fixed by the suggestions in this answer.

Comment: Thanks that helped, also thanks for pointing at the spelling problem.